# Extract one or more consecutive words with first capital letter

Tags: php, regex

I did a regular expression to extract one or more consecutive words with first capital letter. I need it with accented letters, but those letters screw up the expression, generating false output.

This is the example:
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/eHE   (select preg_match_all)

**My regular expression:**

```
/([ÁÉÍÓÚÑA-Z]+[a-záéíóúñ]*[\s]{0,1}){1,}/
```

**Test string:**

> Esto es una prueba para extraer diferentes nombres de personas como Fernández Díaz, Logroño, la Comunidad Valenciana, o también siglas como AVE, y cualquier cosa que empiece por mayúscula y tenga una o varias palabras.

In this case, "úscula", "én" should not appear.

Comment: You should try using `/\b\pLu\w*(?:\h+\pLu\w*)*/u`

Comment: Another variation is `/\b\pLu\pL*(?:\h+\pLu\pL*)*/u`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Are you sure? Both seem to fail...

Comment: [See your updated demo](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/eHH). Need `u (PCRE_UTF8)` [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: When a unicode character class has more than one letter, it must be enclosed between curly brackets: `\p{Lu}` (otherwise it is interpreted as `\pL` and `u`.

Comment: If my mobile keyboard was that easy to use, I would. I always do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_match_all('/(\b\p{Lu}\p{L}+\s*)+/u', $input, $output);`

That's assuming "word" consists of letters only and only words separated by whitespace characters are considered consecutive.

Demo: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/eHG

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in comments, the way to match letters including all accented versions, is to make use of the [`\p` escape sequence](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) in combination with the `u` (unicode) modifier:

> additional escape sequences to match generic character types are available when UTF-8 mode is selected.
>
> \p{xx}
>        a character with the xx property
>
> L       Letter    Includes the following properties: Ll, Lm, Lo, Lt and Lu.
>   Ll       Lower case letter
>   Lm     Modifier letter
>   Lo    Other letter
>   Lt    Title case letter
>   Lu    Upper case letter

You could thus use this regex:

```
\b(?![\h,])(?:[\h,]*\p{Lu}\pL*)+
```

This expression checks that the match does not start with a horizontal white space (`\h`) nor a comma, but then matches words separated by those. You could remove the comma if this is not what you want, or on the other hand add other punctuation to that list if you want.

Note that PHP requires that you use braces when you put more than one letter after the `\p` modifier.

See [PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/eHI)

Example code (see it on [eval.in](https://eval.in/522305)):

```
$text = "Esto es una prueba para extraer diferentes nombres de personas " .
        "como Fernández Díaz, Logroño, la Comunidad Valenciana, o también " .
        "siglas como AVE, y cualquier cosa que empiece por mayúscula " .
        "y tenga una o varias palabras.";

preg_match_all('/\b(?![\h,])(?:[\h,]*\p{Lu}\pL*)+/u', $text, $matches); 

var_export($matches);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Esto',
    1 => 'Fernández Díaz, Logroño',
    2 => 'Comunidad Valenciana',
    3 => 'AVE',
  ),
)
```

Without the commas in the regex, *'Fernández Díaz, Logroño'* would end up in separate matches:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Esto',
    1 => 'Fernández Díaz',
    2 => 'Logroño',
    3 => 'Comunidad Valenciana',
    4 => 'AVE',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Ok, I understand now why you have written that.

Comment: I use to solve this kind of problem more like this: `\b\p{Lu}\pL*(?:[\h,]*\p{Lu}\pL*)*`

Comment: Yes, that would produce the same results. First I had it with just `\h` as separator, and considered my version more compact, but then when adding the comma, I ended up with hardly any savings ;-)